# Does calling main from main spawn a new process?

Tags: c, program-entry-point

Does calling main from main spawn a new process for the called main or does it call main in the same process?

I have read that the value that main returns is returned by the process in which it is executed.

Comment: Why would it ? You're just calling a standard function, just like if you were calling printf or so.

Comment: C has no idea about processes. How would that be possible on a single-process OS like DOS?

Comment: @Olaf funny thing is DOS *does* have a notion of processes, although only one of them runs at a time ... see e.g. [Int 21/AH=26h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2682.htm).

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Doesn't "single-process OS" exactly imply this? How else would a CLI start another program? (I did not program DOS, but TOS very which is very similar).

Comment: @Olaf, I was refering to the part "How would that be possible ..." -- it WOULD be possible even on DOS if C wanted to know about processes. Knowing about processes doesn't necessarily mean multitasking.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Again: that's why I wrote "**single**-process". But I could well have mentioned bare-metal embedded, etc. One fundamental philosophy of C is not to require any run-time (not counting possible startup initialization which can/will be handled by the OS loader).

Comment: @Olaf, just accept that *DOS* ist not the example to make your (otherwise valid) point.

Answer (score 7):

It does not create a new process.  It just calls a function in the same process.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int start=1;

int main()
{
    if (start) {
        printf("in first call to main, pid=%d\n",getpid());
        start=0;
        return main();
    } else {
        printf("in second call to main, pid=%d\n",getpid());
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
in first call to main, pid=15482
in second call to main, pid=15482
```

Process exits with status 1.

Answer (score 1):

It will not create another process, but what it will do is nest main() within itself. There are some weird things that will happen. If you don't explicitly tell main that you are completely done it will keep running and the process will not terminate; because the original call to main has not completed. It is nested within itself when you call it.

Great question. When I was first learning C I had this pop-up. I was using main at the end to rerun everything instead of just using a loop. My teacher said this is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

> I have read that the value that main returns is returned by the process in which it is executed.

This is because the C runtime will call `main()` and after it's execution do some operating-system-specific stuff to set the exit status to whatever `main()` returned. There is, however, nothing special about `main()`, it is just a normal function.

This particularly means it is not the entry point of your program ... the real entry point is provided by the C runtime that is linked to your program and `main()` is called from there.

As an example, see some code I recently wrote for an own runtime for DOS `.COM` executables:

```
__asm__ (
        "   .section    .comstartup             \n"
        "   .globl      __com__start            \n"

        /* THIS is the real entry point, call a function to get some info
         * about the console and then jump to a function getting command
         * line arguments from DOS and calling main */

        "__com__start:                          \n"
        "   call        _getcinfo               \n"
        "   jmp         argstart                \n"
        "   .text                               \n");

void __attribute__((__noreturn__)) exit(int status)
{
    /* this just calls the DOS function for exiting with exit status */
    __asm__ volatile (
            "mov    $0x4c, %%ah     \n\t"
            "int    $0x21           \n\t"
            :
            : "a" (status)
            );
    __builtin_unreachable();
}

static void argstart(void)
{
    char *cmdline = (char *)0x81;
    argc = 1;
    argv[0] = progname();

    {
        /* some code to populate argv[] */
        [....]
    }

    /* and this could be a quite typical line in any C runtime, just
     * call exit() with whatever main() returns: */
    exit(main(argc, argv));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The main function is called in the same process and it can be checked by printing the value returned by getpid() as follows:

```
int main(){
   static int i = 2;
   if (i>0){
      int pid1 = getpid();
      printf("Main: %d\n", pid1);
      i--;
      main();
   }

}
```

The output is

```
Main: 32323
Main: 32323
```

which confirms that main is called in the same process as the first one is called by the system.

Comment: Doing the `int pid1 = getpid(); printf("Main: %d\n", pid1);` outside the `if()` would be stronger evidence.  As far as we know the 3rd time `main()` is called (1st by system, 2x by code), it has a differing pid.